# How to set the width of <h:outputText> of JSF2.0?

Tags: jsf-2

The code:

```
<div>
  <h:outputText value="DelivertyType: " style="width:135px"/>
  <h:inputText value="#{newConsign.consign.faId}" style="width:135px"/>
</div>
```

The style="width:135px" for h:outputText doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The outputText will generate the a span like this :

```
<span style="width: 135px;">DelivertyType:</span>
```

The "width" attribute cannot be applied on in-line elements like SPAN. (can only be applied to block-style elements).

Try wrapping the outputText in a div, and apply the styling on the DIV.

Answer (score 12):

You can force it to display as a block element:

`<h:outputText value="DelivertyType: " style="display:block;width:135px"/>`

this works.