# How to fix the width for a dynamic datatable columns

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

The data in the following picture is dynamic & that is not looking good actually.
I want to fix the width for these columns.

```
                        <p:row styleClass="ui-panelgrid-cell" rowspan="2">

                        <p:column>
                            <div style="overflow: auto; width: 100%;">
                                <p:dataTable var="tPreferences"
                                    value="#{userPreferences.preferences}"
                                    emptyMessage="No Questions Found." id="pTable" styleClass="borderless">
                                    <p:column headerText="PREFERENCES">
                                        <h:outputText id="sName" styleClass="cellLabelMand"
                                            value="#{tPreferences.shortText}" />

                                        <h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />
                                        <h:selectManyCheckbox id="grid"
                                            value="#{tPreferences.preferencesSelectedItem}"
                                            layout="grid" columns="1">

                                            <f:selectItems value="#{tPreferences.catList}" var="pref" />

                                        </h:selectManyCheckbox>
                                    </p:column>
                                </p:dataTable>
                            </div>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647274/houtputtext-is-not-breaking-lines-in-n Here is another good answer for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311619/how-to-set-the-width-of-houtputtext-of-jsf2-0

Comment: But that is for static outputtext. I have to deal with dynamic data.

Comment: First thing you have to break your text so it will not create width issue with the each column

Comment: "break your text" what does it mean ?